# Generic vs static declaration for creating collection instances using google commons

Tags: java, collections

which option is best and why ?

declaration of

1) `List<Employee> employees = Lists.<Employee>newArrayList();`

or

2) `List<Employee> employees = Lists.newArrayList();`

I am making use of com.google.common.collect.Lists for creating Lists Instance

Comment: The entire point of `Lists.newArrayList` is so that you can do 2).  That's pretty much the only reason for its existence.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the implementation:

```
public static <E> ArrayList<E> newArrayList() {
  return new ArrayList<E>();
}
```

So the return list is implicitly converted to the expected type.
There is still a case when the compiler isn't smart enough to figure out the expected type, that's when the method is used as another method's parameter.
For example:

```
public void foo( List<Employee> employees ) {/*do something*/}
```

When you call foo, only the first syntax or an explicit conversion would compile:

```
foo(Lists.<Employee>newArrayList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the second option because the first one will give a warning saying, "Explicit type arguments can be inferred". That's a good enough reason for me, I don't like warnings in my code.

If that warning doesn't make sense to you, it's saying, "Since you have a `List<Employee>` on the left hand side, I already know what you're trying to return on the right hand side so you don't have to explicitly say it."